# What would you call an "almost-closed" roller shutter?

Tags: single-word-requests

We are designing a user interface for the roller shutter users. The ones in question are exterior rollers. These have tiny holes between the slats. You can shut the roller with the holes visible (so some of the outside light still sneaks into the room), or close it fully, enabling you to feel as if you were a mole.

[image: holes]

We are going to use the time taken to reach each state as captions for fields in the user interface, so they should be as concise as possible.

We have not agreed on how to state these questions. The best we've got is "What is the time to shut with unsealed blinds?".

Therefore, I have three questions for you:

1 What would you call the state of roller shutter covering the whole window but with the "holes/rays" visible?

2 What would you call the time required to achieve this state?

3 What would you call the time required to close completely?

Comment: 'Loosely shut' and 'shut tight'. / 'Time required to shut loosely' / 'Total time required to shut tight.'

Comment: This might be more a user-interface thing than an English language one, so I’m putting this in the comments section. Consider providing the picture above and one for the tightly closed state. Label them, then have fields along the lines of “Time(A)” and “Time(B)”.

Comment: If you want to know the time it takes for the bottom of the shutter to reach the bottom of the opening, ask that. Do you want to know the time it takes for the shutter to go from completely open to completely closed or the time between when the bottom of the shutter reaches the bottom of the opening and when the shutter is completely closed? Being precise is more than just choosing the right word to describe something.

Comment: **1** How long does it take for the blind to reach the bottom?” **2** Time to reach the bottom. **3** Time to blackout.

Comment: 1: *splayed*, 2 & 3: and *differential* (presumably you can set the number of seconds it takes)

Comment: Are these roller shutters (always) paired with opening windows? When I've seen them that mode also allows some gentle ventilation , which might give more options for wording

Comment: PLEASE answer this question: When that opening between the slats is larger, are the slats pivoting on an invisible axis (angling), like most louvers OR is the distance between them achieved in the vertical plane?

Comment: It's amazing to me that when the really relevant question is asked, silence descends all around.

Comment: Eyes can be tightly shut, not shutters, unless they are being compared to eyes.

Answer (score 3):

For captions and concise usage, I suggest **nearly closed, tightly closed, time to nearly close, time to tightly close** or, if shorter is needed, **nearly closed time** and **fully closed time.** *Shut* IMO works in *nearly/tightly shut*, but I would use *close the shutter* rather than *shut the shutter.*

You could explain at the first usage that *nearly closed* means almost closed, "with sunlight peeking through the holes."

With regard to questions: *What is the time required/needed to tightly close the shutter?* or *What is the time it takes to nearly close the shutter?*

I lived in Italy, Land of the Roller Shutter, for many years, and *[tapparella socchiusa](https://www.google.com/search?q=tapparella%20socchiusa&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=tapparella%20socchiusa&aqs=chrome..69i57.10136j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* is the term used there for a shutter that's not completely closed, as the illustrations show.

> Tapparella in Alluminio Coibentato con Asola Larga da 18cm per una
> maggiore illuminazione e ricircolo dell'aria *a tapparella socchiusa*

The adjective *socchiuso* itself is often translated using *ajar* or *slightly open.* However, *ajar* in this case gives me the sense of open space under the bottom of the shutter, as might *slightly/partially open.* Other short descriptive phrases I can think of don't work when used before the noun *time.*

Comment: Good answer. My only observation is that “loosely closed” might be better than “nearly closed”. From a security standpoint, both states are “closed”.

Comment: That works and did occur to me.  "Nearly closed" might work a tad better before the word *time.*

Comment: s/peaking/peeking

Comment: fully closed time and nearly closed time do not work in brochure-type language.

Comment: I don't know that the "user interface" the OP refers to is a brochure. It could be a more technical document. At least that was the impression I got.

Comment: I think you mean 'sunlight peeking in'. Not peaking.

Answer (score 3):

'Soft Light Closure' and 'fully dark closure'.

Defining Terms to make your document easier and clearer.

I would give the state of 'light peeking in' a name of its own. to make it easier to talk about it.

I mean, I'd give it a product name like 'Soft Light' or something like that. Then, you can easily talk about 'Soft Light' closure. And you can also then talk about 'fully dark closure' without tying yourself up in knots.

You'll then be able to refer to the 'time for Soft Light closure' and the 'time for fully dark closure' also, without tying yourself up in knots.

You'd start off your document with something like this:

There's a special way of closing our blinds so that light still still peeks in - the shutter is fully secure and closed but some light comes in through unique small apertures. We call this feature 'Soft Light', and we refer to 'Soft Light Closure' when your shutters are like this. When your shutters are fully closed, and completely dark (ie, no apertures are open) we call it 'fully dark closure'.

Having stated this once at the start, you can just refer to 'Soft Light closure' and 'fully dark closure' continually, after that.

Often, legal documents use this technique - they define certain terms up front - and then refer to them in exactly the same way throughout the entire document.  This method is very simple and clear, and I feel it is also well used in brochures or technical documents of the kind that you seem to be making.

You refer to your 'terms' up front, in the introduction - and then refer to them throughout. They can even be listed as 'terms used throughout this document'

As you do seem to have a unique 'product feature' here - why not give it a name?

Note: 'Soft Light' has capitals as it is a suggested 'product name'. 'Fully dark closure' does not, as it is a normal feature of shutters, not a product name.

Here's a good, more detailed description about how the concept of defining terms, described here, is used in legal documents.

https://www.netlawman.co.uk/ia/defined-terms-in-legal-documents

Answer (score 0):

Although used mainly for doors and flat shutters the term *ajar* can reasonably be applied to a roller shutter with a setting like this.

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ajar) and other sources *ajar* is derived from the prefix *a-* (as in aloft, afore, above etc) and the Old English word *charr* meaning an angle. As the movement of the roller feeding out or pulling in the shutter is a rotation through 360 degrees of angle it seems perfectly reasonable to refer to partly opened roller shutter as being *ajar*".

Comment: The problem is that "ajar" indicates not-closed. From the description, their roller door is not only closed but *locked*, while still in the mode that allows some light penetration. The purpose being to be able to close the roller door, lock it, and switch off the interior lights wile still allowing enough light to filter through to enable the person to see what they are doing inside.

Comment: @PcMan If you have a door fitted with a security chain or loop then the door is still secure when it is 'ajar' so long as the chain or loop is in place. Also my UPVc widows can be opened slightly to allow air to pass but still secured with the catch and the catch lock. I would have no problem with saying that they are ajar.

Answer (score 0):

*1 What would you call the state of roller shutter covering the whole window but with the "holes/rays" visible?*

For marketing purposes, I like @Jelila’s idea of coining a term for this partial state of closure in your interface. I suggest “Starlight" mode, to contrast with the fully closed “Dark" mode.

*2 What would you call the time required to achieve this state?*

The time taken to achieve the partly lit closed state could be specified as, “The time taken  from completely open to reach the partially closed Starlight mode is *x* seconds/minutes”.

*3 What would you call the time required to close completely?*

The time taken from completely open to achieve the fully closed state could be specified as, “The time taken to reach the fully closed Dark mode is *x* seconds/minutes”.

Answer (score 0):

*Closed* and *shut* could be mistaken for  *fully extended as a barrier against entry by a person* rather than the desired meaning of "letting some light in/not letting any light in".

You could say

"Time to full occlusion", "Time to partial occlusion".

"Time to zero light", "Time to 5% light". (whatever the percentage may be)

"Time to full dark",  "Time to partial light".

Answer (score -1):

Answering the main question, the terms 'ajar' and 'closed' could be applied to the gap visible below the shutter (the extent to which it is unrolled) so I suggest, from Lexico

> [**translucent**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/translucent)
>
> Allowing light, but not detailed shapes, to pass through; semi-transparent

and

> [**opaque**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/opaque)
>
> Not able to be seen through; not transparent

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: These terms refer to actual objects; not to how light is filtered between them. So these don't work here.

Comment: I think that these terms would work if this was one of those "dimmer" window treatments where you can adjust the opaqueness of the glass with a dial, since the actual material is changing its state (in terms of how much you can see through it.) But you wouldn't say that venetian blinds (for example) become "translucent" when you adjust them so they're mostly closed but still allow in some little bit of light.

Answer (score -1):

These are roll or rolling shutters or roller shutters. Roller is the word in English for a round cylinder. These are not that overall but they have a roller at the top. The shutters are retractable and can be rolled up and down **on a cylinder** at the top of the shutter but each metal **slat** is NOT a roller. These are also called louvers. The shutters are mounted on a roller (cylinder) at the top of the window.

Next: we say:

fully retracted shutters, or rolled all the way up
fully extended shutters, or rolled all the way down

TIME:
full retraction time
full extension time

Then, **the slats can be angled to let in some light or keep it all out:**

to angle them shut or open, or to partially angle them.

- angling a little, angling a lot, no angling

minimum angling, maximum angling, no angling

[roll shutters](https://www.ersshading.com/rolling-exterior-shutters)

Comment: They aren’t really angled though. From what I can tell they are similar to tongue and groove construction where there are some holes in the tongues. When compressed completely the tongues   are fully contained inside the groove of the adjacent slat. When closed but not compressed there is some play between slats and the tongues with holes are visible.

Comment: It's not true that 'roller shutter' is not used for a shutter made of flat slats (or louvres) which roll up onto a large roller at one end (at least in the UK). No one, to my knowledge  makes shutters out of rollers but this sort of shutter is called a 'roller shutter' by makers and installers such as [this one](https://securitydirectuk.com/roller-shutters)

Comment: @BoldBen is right.  "Roller shutter", which is what they're called, refers more to how they work (rollers running in channels) than to the shape of the visible parts.  Downvoted partly because the answer is mainly a (wrong) comment on the (standard) terminology in the question, but also because there's no angling involved so the actual answer in the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Jim The metal cross-bars are called **slats**. Compression is not the right word. Those **slats** can be angled open or can be closed.

Comment: @BoldBen Okay, okay, There are many names: roll shutters, roller shutters. And I already provided a link with the same idea as yours.

Comment: @Lambie - Yes, I used the word slats. And whether compression is the right word is debatable. The slats are either pushed fully together or not. I suspect that they remain apart due to their own weight and begin to close up as the roll at the top continues to turn after the bottom slat reaches the ground.  In that way I think “compress” works to describe the action- a force in the top caused the gaps to close up. All I’m saying (in a non-confrontational way :-) is that I don’t think they angle like plantation shutters.

Comment: @Jim Ok, if they don't angle like plantation shutters, the OP didn't explain this very well. You think the opening between the slats can be made wider or narrower without angling the slats? And only by decreasing/increasing the opening between them without any pivoting? :) I have had to edit poorly translated shutter stuff in English and therefore am interested in how you see this.  (Jim, I never thought you were confrontational. I wish people here would just talk straight like you did and not pussyfoot. :)

Answer (score -1):

I would think “sealed” and “unsealed”. The shutters are sealed against the light, or they aren’t.

So they can be open, closed but unsealed, or closed and sealed. Once people know the terminology, you can drop the “closed but/and”, and just say sealed or unsealed.